# Decrypting a string with RSA returns additional zeros at the beginning

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to generate an AES key, encrypt it and decrypt it using RSA. 
It *kind of* works, except that after decrypting the data and encoding with Base64 I get a pile of "A" letters before my actual string(the base64-encoded AES key). I guess these were zeros in byte.

The "RSA/ECB/NoPadding" parameters are mandatory. What am I doing wrong ? I need it to return the original string/bytes.

```
package szyfrator;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.bzip2.BZip2CompressorInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils;
import org.apache.tools.bzip2.CBZip2OutputStream;

import com.google.common.hash.HashCode;
import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;
import com.google.common.io.Files;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;

public class Cryptography {

    private static byte[] aesKey;
    private static String base64AESKey;
    private static byte[] encryptedAESKey;
    private static String base64AESEncryptedKey;
    private static byte[] aesKeyTransformed;

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Cryptography.generateAESkey();
        Cryptography.encryptAESKey(new File("G:\\HASHBABYHASH\\public.txt"));
        Cryptography.decryptAESKey(new File("G:\\HASHBABYHASH\\private.txt"));

        System.out.println("String: " + Base64.encode(Cryptography.getAesKey()) + "\r\n");
        System.out.println("Encrypted string: " + Cryptography.getBase64EncryptedKey() + "\r\n");
        System.out.println("Decrypted String: " + Base64.encode(Cryptography.getAesKeyTransformed()) + "\r\n");

    }

    public static void generateAESkey(){

        try {
            KeyGenerator    keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");

            keyGen.init(256); 
            SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();

            byte[] keyBytes = secretKey.getEncoded(); 
            base64AESKey = Base64.encode(keyBytes); 

            aesKey = keyBytes;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void encryptAESKey(File publicKeyFile){

        try {       
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFile);

            byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(IOUtils.toByteArray(input));     

            X509EncodedKeySpec publicSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decoded);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);   

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);  

            encryptedAESKey = cipher.doFinal(aesKey);
            base64AESEncryptedKey = Base64.encode(encryptedAESKey);

            input.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void decryptAESKey(File privateKeyFile){

        try {
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile);

            byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(IOUtils.toByteArray(input));

            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decoded);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);  

            aesKeyTransformed = cipher.doFinal(encryptedAESKey);
            input.close();  
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
String: xVwH7Nbz84emVoH0J31sRHC+B669T9wCUVlTDhYgXiI=

Encrypted string: INTA8rx46hX6bZbDIl4iiWsUGO4ywCW0Aee1reqQ3wR5X7He5ztLHvyZoa0WZmUGYbYwprNGffRI
OVJFxczMHkxUfHU1WWCTzcfNylD+sWObIYrbyc13aZi9OL/r1GXuaGtkIgTJyqv0QPHfIri7iaH3
Lr/F4EIcyphJM3E2reQ=

Decrypted String: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAxVwH7Nbz84emVoH0J31sRHC+
B669T9wCUVlTDhYgXiI=
```

Comment: Is the `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` the desired keyspec for decryption? Should be X509, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RSA some data is encoded into a large number and calculated upon. `NoPadding` (unpadded or textbook RSA) means that you're fully responsible for the proper encoding of the message. All of the calculations are done against a large modulus (should be at least 2048 bit nowadays). Since Java assumes big-endian numbers, your message is encoded into the least significant bytes automatically, but the decryption returns the decoded message in the same size of the modulus, because it cannot know whether the leading zero-bytes where intentional or not.

In order to make this calculation correct *and secure* it is necessary to apply padding. The old-style PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is not considered secure nowadays, but it only has 11 bytes of overhead (only 2048/8-11=245 bytes can be encrypted with a key of 2048 bit). The newer PKCS#1 v2.1 padding (OAEP) is considered secure and should be used here. It does have an overhead of 42 bytes if SHA-1 is used.

> The "RSA/ECB/NoPadding" parameters are mandatory.

This is really bad, because it is very insecure: [Which attacks are possible against raw/textbook RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20085/13022)

If you're not willing to simply change the cipher string to `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");`, you will have to remove the leading zeros yourself. The problem is of course that this "zero-padding" mode is ambiguous and if the plaintext begins with a 0x00 byte, you will not be able to distinguish it from a padding byte and will have to remove it, thus breaking your plaintext. **If the plaintext is an AES key as in your case, there is a 0.3% chance that it begins with a 0x00 byte and thus breaks the key.** You will have to make sure that the key is actually correct and fill up with zero bytes if it has not the correct length.

Here is how you can remove leading zero bytes:

```
byte[] unpadZeros(byte[] in) {
    int i = 0;
    while(in[i] == 0) i++;
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(in, i, in.length);
}
```

If you know that you're decrypting an AES key, then it's possible to make the unpadding no produce wrong data:

```
byte[] unpadZerosToGetAesKey(byte[] in) {
    int i = 0;
    while(in[i] == 0) i++;
    int len = in.length - i;
    if (len <= 16) len = 16;
    else if (len <= 24) len = 24;
    else len = 32;
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(in, in.length - len, in.length);
}
```

Comment: Funny (or sad) thing about these parameters is, that they had been imposed by the tax office in my country =). The second method is exacly what i need, thanks.